# How to register function by poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Does anyone know how to register a function which cannot be implemented by poi?
For example: intercept?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what sort of function you want to implement. Is it one of the excel built-in functions that have a special pre-defined ID in the file format, for which POI doesn't currently have an implemention? Or is it for a user defined function? (Some of the more recent excel functions are actually implemented as UDFs in the file format)

If it's the latter, then there's excellent documentation on how to do that on the [POI Website](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/user-defined-functions.html) - I'd suggest you [follow it](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/user-defined-functions.html) and you should be fine!

If it's the former, then it's a little trickier. Your best bet is to implement the formula yourself, open an enhancement bug in the [POI Bugzilla](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?product=POI) and attach your implementation, then grab a nightly build with your fix included. For testing, you'll need to edit the functions metadata file, to register your class against the file-format ID of the function. It's a little fiddly, but if everyone contributed one missing function to POI then we'd be there in no time!

*Update:* Some more info on implementing a built in function. First, find the ID of the function in [functionMetadata.txt](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/resources/main/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/function/functionMetadata.txt) (311 for your case). Next, implement the function. Now, customise `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.FunctionEval` and add your function in at the appropriate index. Finally, submit a patch! (It's semi-deliberately hard to override built-in functions, partly to encourage people to contribute the missing ones!)

Comment: I want to implement function "intercept" which is a regular excel function, not a customer function, and it cannot be evaluated by poi now. I found "svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/resources/main/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/function/functionMetadata.txt" in poi website and the function is defined as "New Built-In Sheet Functions in BIFF4", but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I cannot understand you clearly. Could you explain it more specific?Should I code the function by myself?

Comment: Yes. If you want to use a function that POI doesn't currently have an implementation of, then you'll need to write it yourself, then please contribute it back!

Comment: I just need 'intercept' function.Do you mean I have to write intercept function by myself? What's that meansd of functionMetada.txt? Have the functions listed in that file been implemented?

Comment: Yes, you need to write it yourself, it's not currently implemented. FunctionMetadata tells you about the IDs, arguments etc that functions should have